# Why would an array filling program crash at a given iteration, when giving a large number - but surpass that iteration when given a smaller number

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I was trying to replicate a bug today that was related to either the number of rows, or size of a dataset (not super important which) - while trying to replicate this, I populated an array with a lot of objects, my plan being to populate a massive array with small objects until I hit a memory limit.

```js
const someRows = _.times(numRows, (i) => {
    if (i % 10000 === 0) {
      console.log(i, process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024);
    }
    return {
      col1: "testa",
      col2: "testa"
    }
  });
```

If I pass in a large number, e.g., 323690000 it will die with the following result:

```
22369000 2425.549415588379

<--- Last few GCs --->

[1130801:0x3a01e80]     1137 ms: Scavenge 32.9 (43.8) -> 29.8 (62.8) MB, 8.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure 
[1130801:0x3a01e80]     1199 ms: Mark-sweep 40.9 (71.8) -> 34.0 (71.0) MB, 5.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 30.0 ms in 88 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 334 ms) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old spa[1130801:0x3a01e80]     7327 ms: Scavenge 1207.5 (1235.0) -> 1195.9 (1237.0) MB, 25.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->
```

What's really weird is, if I pass in a smaller number, e.g., 32369000, it will happily generate them all - even though `32369000 > 22369000` - it's worth noting that I'm nowhere close to being out of memory, as I run the program with `--max_old_space_size=8192`. It also doesn't seem to matter how big the return value is (I tried defining 20 columns) - it always dies around the 22369000 mark, if I pass in a huge value, and happily goes further if I give it a smaller value

This makes me think there is some weird bug in how `_.times` works (I should probably swap to Array.fill or some such). I looked at the implementation of `_.times` and it doesn't seem to be doing anything particualarly ineficient (it generates an empty array at the start and then fills it). Nothing that I would expect should cause this.